# CASTEP: Tools for extracting .castep output into OriginLab or similar programs for plotting

Tags: density-functional-theory, castep

I'm currently picking up CASTEP for geometry optimization and am following the website's tutorials.

Strangely, none of the documentation indicates how one should *efficiently* extract information from CASTEP files, despite the fact that the output files are in a human readable format, instead of a machine readable format.  For example, I need to test for convergence, and copying and pasting the forces and stresses for even a single calculations is a tedious and error prone task.  I highly doubt that this is how regular users actually analyze their data.  Presumably, they use a tool to extract the information out from the binary files.

I haven't been able to find an obvious, or standard, tool for dealing with castep output.   No one around me uses CASTEP.  And I doubt everyone else paid for Materials Studio.  So, I have to ask:  What are the standard tools people use for plotting output from .castep files?

Comment: I am willing to start using CASTEP too, and that is one of my concerns. Looking at [Github](https://github.com/search?q=castep&type=repositories), there are several tools that claim to read CASTEP output.

Comment: https://github.com/CCP-NC/castepconv is a good place to start for convergence testing, and c2x can extract most of the binary checkpoint file information if that's what you need - alternatively if you know Python you can easily write your own using the DFT Python API

Comment: @PhilHasnip  by DFT Python API, did you mean [this](https://pypi.org/project/dft-python-api/)?

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin yes, CASTEP has a complete implementation of that API -- there's also ASE, of course, but that's mostly file-based.

Answer (score 3):

I have used CASTEP a lot, through the Materials Studio suite though. Initially, I was doing everything manually, but as you mentioned, it is a very tedious task. I ended up writing my own codes to extract the information I needed. Let me give you an example of one I have used to extract the final energy and some other info. I used R. It is for sure not the most efficient nor the most elegant way to do it, but it is a start. In addition, you can check this [publication](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/admi.202370038). All the numerical analysis was done using a simple R code.

````
#This script imports and reads CASTEP files within a directory for extracting the lattice parameters, final volume, final enthalpy, functional used, and whether long-range dispersion correction was used for the calculations or not.

# the program exports the data into a excel (.xlsx) file. Name is provided by the user. Default location for exporting the file is in the same working directory of the R script
 
#
# setting location of the working directory (for the R script)
#
setwd("C:\\Users\\...\\script\\")

# loading libraries

library(readr)
library(pracma)
library(openxlsx) # for writing in excel format

# getting CASTEP files into a list

print("Introduce the complete route of castep files:")
print("Path must be in the format accepted in R, like 'C:\\Users\\ ...' or 'C:/Users/...' ")
castep_files_list <- list.files(readline(),all.files = FALSE,full.names = TRUE)

# creating the data structure to store the values that will be extracted
castep_data <- data.frame(
  Functional = c(""),
  DFTD = c("On/Off"),
  Volume = c("cubic angstrom"),
  Enthalphy = c("eV"),
  a = c("angstrom"),
  b = c(""),
  c = c(" "),
  alpha = c(" "),
  beta = c(" "),
  gamma = c(" ")
  
  )

# we have to iterate through each element of the list to read the file
# main 'for' loop
for(i in 1:length(castep_files_list)){
  # castep_files[i]
  # storing the file 'castep_files[i]' in "filetxt' variable
  castep_file <- read.delim(file = castep_files_list[i], header = FALSE, sep = "\n", quote="")
  
  # getting the type of functional used
  for (j in 1:length(row(castep_file))) {
    if(grepl("using functional", castep_file[j,]))
      functional <- castep_file[j,]
      #print()
  }
  
  # checking if a long-range dispersion correction was used
  for (j in 1:length(row(castep_file))) {
    if(grepl("dispersion correction", castep_file[j,]))
      dftd_correction <- castep_file[j,]
    #print()dftd_correction
  }
  
  # # extracting the final volume of the structure
  # for (j in 1:length(row(castep_file))) {
  #   if(grepl("Current cell volume", castep_file[j,]))
  #      castep_file[j,]
  #     cell_volume <- castep_file[j,]
  #     # castep_file[j,]
  #   # "cell_volume not found" bug. check why the initial values is requiered

      # extracting the value of the final volume after geometry optimization in numeric format, without string or other characters
      # unit_cell_volume <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(cell_volume,gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",cell_volume, perl=TRUE))))
      # unit_cell_volume <- unit_cell_volume[1]
  #}
  
  # getting the final lattice constants of the structure (a,b & c)
  # Lattice parameters(A) and cell angles
  for (j in 1:length(row(castep_file))) {
    if(grepl("Final Configuration", castep_file[j,])){
      values_a <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(castep_file[j+12,],gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",castep_file[j+12,], perl=TRUE))))
      values_b <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(castep_file[j+13,],gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",castep_file[j+13,], perl=TRUE))))
      values_c <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(castep_file[j+14,],gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",castep_file[j+14,], perl=TRUE))))
    }
  } 
  # getting the value of the final enthalpy (as a string)
  for (j in 1:length(row(castep_file))) {
    # condition specifically design to read CASTEP files with the exact string
    if (grepl("Final Enthalpy", castep_file[j,])){
      energy <- castep_file[j,]
      #extracting the value of the final enthalpy
      enthalpy_value <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(energy,gregexpr("(?>-)*[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*",energy, perl=TRUE))))
    }}
  
  final_enthalpy_value <- enthalpy_value[1]*10^enthalpy_value[2]
  # in units of eV
  
  # calculating the volume of the unit cell
  unit_cell_volume <- values_a[1]*values_b[1]*values_c[1]
  # storing the newly extracted values into one temporarily data frame
  # columns name must be the same, adding the values as lists of one element
  temp_data <- data.frame(Functional = c(functional),
                          DFTD = c(dftd_correction),
                          Volume = c(unit_cell_volume),
                          Enthalphy = c(final_enthalpy_value),
                          a = c(values_a[1]),
                          b = c(values_b[1]),
                          c = c(values_c[1]),
                          alpha = c(values_a[2]),
                          beta = c(values_b[2]),
                          gamma = c(values_c[2])
                          )
  
  # adding new values to the previously created data frame
  castep_data <- rbind(castep_data,temp_data)
  
}

# exporting the data frame to an excel (.xlsx) file
# requesting the name of the file to the user
print("Insert name of file (e.g., /file_name.xlsx)")
name <- readline() #inserting the name of the file in the specified format
write.xlsx(castep_data, name) #writing the data in a .xlsx file
print("file exported successfully :)")
print("file located in:")
print(getwd())
```
````